# While using select in 'antd' library (Ant Design) the selected option is showing value instead of label

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I am using select in the 'antd' (Ant Design) library. The selected option is showing the value of the option instead of the the label when using an onChange Handler.

I am adding the working example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bordered-less-antd-4-17-0-alpha-7-forked-5kg4v?file=/index.js). In the example I have commented out the onChange in DATA1 so it works as expected.

```
 <Select        
        // onChange={(key, val) => onChangeHandler1(key, val)}
        placeholder="Select any one"
        style={{ width: 120 }}
        options={data
          .filter((d) => d.disabled === false)
          .map((_) => {
            return {
              label: _.name,
              value: _.id
            };
          })}
        bordered={false}
      />
```

When the onChange is commented out the behaviour is as expected, the selected value shows the label(name) instead of the value(id).

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Just add the value prop to both selects. Eg:-

```
<Select value={option1} .../>
<Select value={option2} .../>
```